# Get Employees Who Are Below Average Salary After A Raise

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, where-clause

I need to get fname, lname, salary of employees who are $400.00 below the average salary even after geting a 10% salary raise.

I'm able to get employees who's salary is below the average salary, but am unsure how to get those who are $400 below after a raise.

I'm using MySQL. Thank you.

```
select AVG(salary) from employee; #gives me the average salary
```

```
select Fname, Lname, Salary, 1.10*Salary as NewSalary
from employee; 
#gives me names, old salary and salary raised.
```

This gives me the employees with salary less than the average salary:

```
select Fname, Lname, Salary
from employee
where Salary < (select AVG(salary) from employee);
```

I was thinking something like this, but this doesn't work; unknown column newsalary:

```
select Fname, Lname, Salary, 1.10*Salary as NewSalary
from employee
where NewSalary - (select AVG(salary) from employee) = 400 ;
```

Comment: You cannot use column aliases in the `WHERE`. Instead of the alias repeat the actual expression like `...WHERE 1.10 * Salary - (...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, you just can't use aliases in the `where` clause like that. Just use the formula directly, and you should be fine. Also, you should probably use `<=`, and not `=`:

```
select Fname, Lname, Salary, 1.10 * Salary as NewSalary
from   employee
where  1.10 * Salary - (select AVG(salary) from employee) <= 400;
```

Answer (score 0):

select Fname, Lname, Salary, 1.10 * Salary as NewSalary
from   employee
where  ((1.10 * Salary) - (select AVG(salary) from employee)) <= 400;

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one statement by using HAVING

```
select Fname, Lname, AVG(salary * 1.10)    
FROM employee
GROUP BY FNAME, LNAME 
HAVING (AVG(salary) * 1.10) = 400
```

But I don't understand the concept of average salary of an employee in a table.
You could be looking for an average salary of a group of employees perhaps?
Or maybe you are storing historical values of salaries, but again I see no purpose of calculating average of that.